# How to save performance counter data to disc

Tags: csv, performancecounter, perfmon

I want to monitor performance of a server and want to save the data of some counters in a csv file so that I can analyze the same later. I can do this using perfmon but I have to do it manually. Is there a way or some tools which can help me do this automatically?

Answer (score 1):

First create a counter file, e.g. counter.txt containing counters you are interested in.
Then add this counter to perfmon. Use following commands to:

create a counter

```
logman create
```

start collecting data

```
logman start
```

stop collecting data

```
logman stop
```

remove the counter

```
logman delete
```

logman create accepts several switches and one of them is logfile path and format.  In some instances you may have to create an empty logfile otherwise logman will complain that it can not create log file.